# Why is my code generating two columns with same name RoleLookupId and RoleLookupId1

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I created the userclass with a foreign key and a navigational property with it.

```
namespace Faculty_Information_System_Application.Data
{
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter the Role"), MaxLength(1)]
        public int RoleLookupId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter username Name"), MaxLength(10)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public virtual RoleLookup RoleLookup {get; set;}

    }
}
```

below is the rolelookup where the RoleLookupId is as primarykey. Yet, when I am creating the database it's creating two columns with same name in the user table....

```
namespace Faculty_Information_System_Application.Data
{
    public class RoleLookup
    {
        public RoleLookup()
        {
            Administrators = new HashSet<Administrator>();
            Users = new HashSet<User>();
        }

        [Key]
        public short RoleLookupId { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Administrator> Administrators { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code for the `RoleLookup` class.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks for the reply. I have edited the question with rolelookup class. please have a look.

Comment: Which column is being created twice? How are you validating this?

Comment: in user table where roleLookupId  is fK, is being generated twice by the name rolelookupid and rolelookupid1

Comment: Possible answer below, make sure you recreate the Db fully again or roll back any migrations

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the ForeignKey attribute to the virtual that you have, something like:

```
    [ForeignKey(nameof(RoleLookupId))]
    public virtual RoleLookup RoleLookup {get; set;}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, After using your code.. I came to realize that the issue was actually at declaring datatype, in the rolelookup I decared the Id by short type but while declaring it in the user class, I declaring it with int, that's why entity was creating two different column by assiging 1 in the end with same name.